# PHP + Exim4 on Debian - mail does not get delivered

Tags: debian, php, sendmail, exim

I have a fresh Debian installation with LAMP. There is a PHP script that sends email messages to arbitrary addresses using the `mail` function, but it does not work - the messages don't get delivered.

I have been searching the internet for quite a while and found out that there already is a SMTP server installed by default on Debian - the exim4 package. So I tried the following things so far.

1. Launch the `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` command and choose the `internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP` option. Follow the wizard and set the default options.
2. Edit the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file and add the `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t` line on the appropriate spot.

None of those things have helped. When I try to send emails to my testing GMail address, it is not delivered, even though the address otherwise works fine.

The following lines appear in my `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` file everytime I try to send an email.

```
2013-08-16 10:46:51 1VAFgI-0006FP-UU <= www-data@vps02.4jt.eu U=www-data P=local S=423
2013-08-16 10:46:51 1VAFgI-0006FP-UU => dusan@jezek.biz R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=aspmx.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b] X=TLS1.2:RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1:128 DN="C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=mx.google.com"
2013-08-16 10:46:51 1VAFgI-0006FP-UU Completed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure exim4 to relay as a *smarthost*. There are a (lengthy) set of instructions here at the [Debian wiki: GmailAndExim4](https://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4), but it's really easy to get up and running. Your PHP `sendmail_path` is good to go.

Comment: What if I didn't won't it to run in the smart host mode, but as a standalone SMTP server (i.e. the internet site option)? Would that be possible?

Comment: In that case you'd need to set up exim as a full-blown smtp relay server (presumably) locked down to allow only actual system users on localhost to relay. I'm only familiar with setting up exim as a smarthost, so you'll need to read a guide on how to set it up. There is no "quick fix" answer for setting up a smtp relay server. Also, if you go that route you'll need to configure reverse dns on your server so sent mail isn't dropped as spam by receiving servers.

Comment: OK, I'll go with the smarthost then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No you DON'T need to configure exim4 as a smarthost. The "internet site; ..." configuration is fine. With no relying and listening only to 127.0.0.1 (and ::1 if you have ipv6). I myself have it set up this way and it works. So I don't know the answer but this answer is definitely wrong (at least the part that says "you need to").